# MYSQL Select where string contains keywords

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, sql-like

So, I've been doing some digging but I can't really find something specific. Let's say I have a table called `products` with 2 columns: `product_name` and `vendor`.

```
product_name  |  vendor
Item A        | Computer Mania
Item B        | Incredible Connection
Item C        | Computer Mania
```

So, now let's say hypothetically I don't remember how to spell `computer` and I say, okay I remember the name starts with `co` and ends with `er` and there is `mania` afterwards.

How can I build a SELECT query with those conditions in my WHERE? I have no idea how to do it.

Here's what I tried:
`SELECT * FROM products WHERE vendor_name LIKE '%co%';`

However this returns `Incredible Connection` as well, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `REGEXP` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WNERE vendor REGEXP '^co[a-z]*er mania';
```

This regex pattern says to find all vendors whose names have a first word starting with `co` and ending in `er`, followed by the word `mania`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use SQL Wildcards properly.

The `%` wildcard represents zero or more characters. So, if you use `%co%`, it will search the string `co` in the vendor column. `vendor` column in given example in the question has the string `co` in every row.

If you say that it starts with `co` and ends with `er mania`, then use the wildcards as `vendor like 'co%er mania'`. This will search the `vendor` column for the values which starts with `co` and ends with `er mania`

```
select * from products where vendor like 'co%er mania';
```

Refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) to read more about SQL Wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you would use `like`:

```
where vendor_name like 'co%er mania'
```

You may want to make this case independent as well, although that is the default in MySQL.